# Modify remote machine input.properties file from web page

Tags: c#, .net

i have build script in remote machine.but i want to start the build from my local machine.so for this i need to update the input.properties file in remote machine and then run the batch file to start the build process. For this i have created one web page
[image: i am selecting all the build information upto input property and then i want to modify the patch name and revision number for build in that input properties.After this i want to trigger one batch file(buildstart.bat) to start the build which is in same folder after clicking on Start Build button]

so how can i modify the remote input.properties file and run the batch file in C#.
please give me some suggestion for this.
thanks in advance...

Comment: input properties is one text file containing all the information like svn revision number, branch name for which build is going to start FTP location where patch will place after build completion.eg:-`

project.name=AM - CS 2.0.2
client.name=Mercuria
build.priority=Scheduled
build.source=Development

BR.number=1354469
rev=46014

linkd.jms=C:/JMSFolders/JMSP_MET_2.1_43626_Core
patch.name=P_MET_2.1_43626_sp36
workareas.dir=c:/workareas/P_MET_2.1_43626
patch.dir=c:/Patches/P_MET_2.1_43626
project.svn.url=P_MET_2.1
svn.username=vkalyani
svn.password=`

Comment: What is that you edit in this file?

Comment: here need to edit BR.number,rev,patch.name....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the properties file remotely, using a Stream Reader / Stream Writer. There are many ways to do that. You should be able to solve that yourself.

Once you are happy that the properties file is updated correctly you will need to use PSEXEC service to launch the Batch file locally on the User's machine. So in this case, the batch file needs to be copied over to the remote machine.

What I normally do is write the Batch file your intending on using to the remote machine on the fly, and as soon as I can see that the associated process has finished, I remove the batch file from the local machine.

PSEXEC will be ran at your end, you use it to connect up to the end users machine and fire the batch file.

You can create a process like below :-

```
       Process p = new Process();
       p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
       p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
       p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\psexec.exe";
       p.StartInfo.Arguments = "\\\\" + computerName + " C:\\YourBatFile.bat";
       p.Start();
       p.WaitForExit();
```

This will open a process on the local machine, that will launch your batch file.

I would recommend learning about the PSEXEC Service, its how I've always launched remote processed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i m able to run the batch file in remote machine.but i want to print the output of batch file into one textbox in my windowsform. for local batch file it's printing the output in textbox but for remote batch file it's not writing. below is the code snnipet.

Comment: `myProcess = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("psexec.exe");
myProcessStartInfo.Arguments = "\\\\machine -u DOMAIN\\usr -p pass C:\\Temp\\run.bat";
myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
myProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
myProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
myProcess.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(myProcess_OutputDataReceived);
myProcess.Start();
myProcess.WaitForExit();
myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();`

Comment: You can achieve this by capturing the output in a string object and then setting the Text prperty of your textbox to the String Object. Something like :- string output = myProcess.StandardOutput;  this should work mate i think.

Comment: but i think it will catch all the output text and then it will put in textbox all at a time. But i want to show like run time output window.

Comment: Ahh I see. I' not sure on that one I'm afraid.